# Storage plugin configuration persistence not working for Apache Drill

Tags: apache-drill

According to Drill's [documentation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/storage-plugin-registration/#storage-plugin-configuration-persistance) :

> Drill uses `/tmp/drill/sys.storage_plugins` to store storage plugin configurations. The temporary directory clears when you quit the Drill shell. To save your storage plugin configurations from one session to the next, set the following option in the drill-override.conf file if you are running Drill in embedded mode.
>
> `drill.exec.sys.store.provider.local.path = "/mypath"`

I checked `/tmp/drill/sys.storage_plugins`, there is some data in this file. Then I modified `drill-override.conf` :

```
drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "drillbits1",
  zk.connect: "localhost:2181",
  drill.exec.sys.store.provider.local.path = "/home/dev/abc"
}
```

I restarted drill & even restarted my machine. Nothing is created at this location.

**Note:** I am using ubuntu 14.0.4 & Drill version - 1.3. Drill is running in embedded mode

Any pointer on this.

Comment: I think this is an issue for the Drill team. To get a fix, please open a JIRA to describe the problem from a user point of view (might help to see some history: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-3949). Alternatively, raise the issue on the Drill user list. In the meantime, until we have a fix, copy sys.storage_plugins to a secure location to save configurations in embedded mode in the event of a reboot. In 1.4 and perhaps since 1.2, my test shows no problem with persistence between sessions--sys.storage_plugins persists. The docs, which you correctly cited, have been changed.

Comment: @catpaws I raised  issue (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-4208) for the same.

Comment: Thanks @dev. Corrected docs with info from the guru: use sys.store.provider.local.path = "/mypath"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I raised an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-4208) regarding this. It is **resolved**.

Use  `sys.store.provider.local.path` instead of `drill.exec.sys.store.provider.local.path` because it's already in `drill.exec`

Modified drill-override.conf :

```
drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "drillbits1",
  zk.connect: "localhost:2181",
  sys.store.provider.local.path = "/home/dev/abc"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Use this..**

```
drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "drillbits1",
  zk.connect: "localhost:2181",
  sys.store.provider.local.path="",
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".